# Keycloak secured service returning 503 when accessing from a webserver

Tags: keycloak, single-sign-on, reverse-proxy

Good day. I have spring application container which is secured by Keycloak. This app is running perfectly on my host server. But when I try to access the same app from over my webserver, I get error 503
"ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved"
with details

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://keycloak:8080/realms/ShootingStar/protocol/openid-connect/auth?

Unable to determine IP address from host name keycloak

The DNS server returned:

Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
```

I have an apache server that resolves my DNS "orb.astromyllc.com" to the host machine and on the host machine I have nginx with the following config

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name orb.astromyllc.com;

     location / {
        proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I will really appreciate it if someone can help me resolve this. Thank you in advance